# How do we setscale of a decimal

Tags: apex

I have a decimal variable and i am setting the value of the decimal by using a formula

```
Decimal test=0;
test = (a.Date_of_First_Order__c.daysBetween(lastDateForMonthOfRating) /(365*12));
//assuming the days between returns 30
// test should hold 0.0068493
system.debug(test); // But it holds 0
test.setscale(4);
 system.debug(test); // But it still holds 0
```

Is there any way to get the whole value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're dividing an integer by an integer, so you're ending up with an integer.

Change the calculation to this:

```
test = (a.Date_of_First_Order__c.daysBetween(lastDateForMonthOfRating) /(365 * 12.0));
```

The type of an expressions is determined by the types of the operands, and an operand can be converted to a more precise type if needed. Theses are called arithmetic conversions. I can't find the details for Apex in particular right now [but this MSDN article explains it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09ka8bxx%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

[There is some discussion in the developer guide regarding numeric types](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf), but it doesn't talk in detail about the promotion rules used:

> Additional Considerations for Data Types Data Types of Numeric Values
>   Numeric values represent Integer values unless they are appended with
>   L for a Long or with .0 for a Double or Decimal. For example, the
>   expression Long d = 123; declares a Long variable named d and assigns
>   it to an Integer numeric value (123), which is implicitly converted to
>   a Long. The Integer value on the right hand side is within the range
>   for Integers and the assignment succeeds. However, if the numeric
>   value on the right hand side exceeds the maximum value for an Integer,
>   you get a compilation error. In this case, the solution is to append L
>   to the numeric value so that it represents a Long value which has a
>   wider range, as shown in this example: Long d = 2147483648L;.